# Joining a domain and domain accounts

Tags: windows-7, windows-server-2008, windows-domain

I'm new to servers and domains.. but I'm learning and have some questions!

**Scenario:**

I'm using VM ware and have created one machine with Windows 7, one with Windows server 2008 R2. Also I've created a custom virtual network with no external access.

I've only set up VMs with static IP and subnet mask.

I've only set up the installation accounts on each machine.

After starting up the VMs, I tried to ping the VMs, from each other, without success. After either disabling windows firewall or creating a rule this succeeded.

On the server I've installed 'Active Directory Domain Services' and ran dcpromo 
(new domain in a new forest)

FQDN: testlab.local

Forest functional level: Windows server 2008 R2

Additional options: DNS server and Global Catalog

**Now to the questions:**

1. When I try to join the domain from the Win7 machine, without having setup any DNS information I, of course, get an error message when I try to join the "testlab.local" domain. But if I only write "testlab" as domain name I get to a logon window and then it fails.. Why is the reason for this? Does it actually find the domain in the second case or is it just an illusion?
2. When I've set up the DNS information in Win7 and try to join the domain and I give the admin username and password for the Win2008 and it succeeds. Is this the preferred way? Or can I use another account for this? I notice that there exist a group called 'Domain Admins'. Is this the preferred one to join computers to the domain?
3. If I disable a computer on the domain. What am I preventing then? If I log on with the local administrator (which I assume I can?) will it still be connected to the domain?
4. When I installed (for example) the DNS server and look in the server manager I see a Warning (ID 4013) and some Information. What is the way of working with the logs? My thought was to clear them (if possible?) once everything has been set up. But maybe it is customary to just filter out the events?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: That's 11 questions. Please don't do that. Voting to Close as "Too Broad".

Comment: Yes it is 11 question marks but hardly 11 questions.. someone with knowledge could probably answer each of the four main questions with one sentence.